# trying to add a parameter to initWithNibName -> error No visible @interface

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This is my first post, thx, you've been very helpful. But I'm stuck. I tried to implement : [xcode init controller with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787395/xcode-init-controller-with-data)

when I initialize my controller with the new parameter I get : No visible @interface for 'VisiteViewController' declares the selector 'initWithNibName:bundle:texte:'

in VisiteViewController.m I've got :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil texte:(NSString *)chaine{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;}
```

and I call it like this:

```
- (IBAction)goToVisite: (id)sender{
NSLog(@"Button pushed");
VisiteViewController *visiteViewController = [[VisiteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VisiteViewController" bundle:nil texte:@"lkj"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:visiteViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Thx for your help

Comment: did you add these to your header file? - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil texte:(NSString *)chaine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

As @janusfidel mentioned, you need to add the declaration to the header (.h) file.

You did not *change* a method, you created an entirely new one (that - just coincidentally - has a name that looks a bit like one of the existing methods, but the computer has no concept of that). You now have to announce to everybody using your class that there is a new method whose selector (name, basically) is `initWithNibName:bundle:texte:`. This does not overwrite, remove, or otherwise interact with the method `initWithNibName:bundle:`, nor with the method `init` or any other method. The similarity in names is basically just there to give the human reader (i. e. you) a clue as to what those methods do[1].

Please do not take this personally, but do yourself a favor and get a good book on programming in Objective-C (or object-oriented programming in general). This will make your first steps *a lot* easier and faster. The Big Nerd Ranch Guides are an excellent series of books, and I would recommend you to buy *iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide* as soon as you can.

[1]: Technically, there are some naming guidelines that also give clues to the compiler on how to handle memory management in Objective-C, but going into that would just be confusing for now.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: Care to explain why, so I can improve the answer?

Comment: ok I agree : rookie mistake. Thx even if I take it a bit personally.

Comment: No need to take it personally: It's not been that long ago that I've read the first edition of that book myself. It's nothing to be ashamed of. On the contrary: You would be doing yourself (and your users!) a disservice by not trying to learn from what I consider one of the best resources out there.